# Nativescript http post failing with no exception thrown

Tags: http, post, nativescript

I am trying to call an api and post a simple json string. when debugging using VS Code, the function appears to work but nothing is returned.  I suspect I don't have the headers correct.  Here is my code:

```
{return this.http.post(
           url,
           content,
            { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
        ).pipe(
            map(response => response.json()),
            tap(data => {
                console.log(data.systemAssignId)
                this.san = data.systemAssignId            
            }),
            catchError(this.handleErrors)
        );}
```

The getCommonHeaders function looks like this:

```
getCommonHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer "+ Config.token.toString().trim);
        headers.append("Content-type", "application/json")
        return headers;
    }
```

I've been struggling with this for hours now.  I must be missing something fundamental but cannot seem to catch it.  The API works fine from Postman.

Comment: Looking at your code I believe you are using Angular. You should use HttpClient instead of Http module which was deprecated long back. With HttpClient the default response format is JSON.

Comment: thanks! I switched over to the httpClient and that resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **HttpClient** instead of **Http** module which was deprecated long back. With HttpClient the default response format is JSON.